# Laravel 4 on Mac localhost: Cannot find driver for SQLSRV

Tags: php, macos, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to connect with Laravel 4 to an SQL Server database.  I'm getting an error, but I think it's a PHP error, not a Laravel error.  It says `PDOException: could not find driver`.  I have the driver set to `sqlsrv` like another example in the `database.php` file.  Like I said, I think this is a PHP error, not Laravel.

I'm on localhost on my Mac.  Do I need to configure something in my `php.ini` file?  I found [another article](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2291) that said I need to comment out a MySQL driver under PDO.  I also couldn't find that line in my `php.ini`.  But I need to connect to a MySQL database as well, anyway.  What do I need to change in my `php.ini` file?

I found this line:

`pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000`

But commenting it out did nothing even after restarting Apache.

Comment: What SQL server are you connecting to? mysql, mssql, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Ok, yo need to compile php with mssql. You can find a tutorial here: http://www.screensugar.co.uk/2010/12/php-with-mssql-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/ Or try uncommenting this line in php.ini:`extension=mssql.so`.

Comment: Ugh.  Ok, thanks, John.

Answer (score 6):

The sqlsrv driver is a windows-only driver according to the PHP Manual (www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php). So you can't use that driver on Mac, Linux, Unix or any other operating system than the ones listed on that page.

I assume you are trying to connect to a remote SQL Server somewhere? If you're on Mac, then SQL Server wouldn't be running on your local machine, so I guess the first question is whether or not you have a SQL Server running somewhere.

Second, from the server that is running PHP, you would need to connect using either FreeTDS or ODBC with FreeTDS.

Since Laravel 4 uses PDO, you'll need to install FreeTDS and ODBC. Laravel 4 doesn't use the mssql PHP extension. It uses PDO, so mssql won't get you anywhere with Laravel 4.

If you're serving PHP from your Mac, I would say there are generally 4 different ways you could go:

1. The Easy, but costly way: Go to (www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23152/openlink-odbc-driver-for-sybase) and download and install OpenLink ODBC driver. This allows you to create new ODBC connections using the Sybase (MSSQL) driver on a XNIX machine. There's an installation walk-through here (wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/UdaWikiWeb/InstallSybaseExpressOSX). It comes with a 15 day trial, after which you would have to purchase it. As of this writing, it appears to cost somewhere in the range of $30 - $50 depending on the license you choose.
2. The harder, but free way: Follow http://blog.benjaminwalters.net/?p=10 (slightly outdated) to re-compile FreeTDS support into PHP on Mac (assuming you're using MAMP)
3. The far better, but also far more work way: Find a Virtual Machine Host software like VMWare Fusion and install a Linux server like Ubuntu 12.4. Make sure you install apache2 and PHP during the install process and then follow the steps [here](http://davejamesmiller.com/blog/connecting-php-to-microsoft-sql-server-on-debian-ubuntu) to get FreeTDS working on your new server machine.
4. Run PHP from the Windows Server that is running SQL Server

Milage will vary with each solution, and there is a learning curve in any case. I've been a PHP developer for a long time, and it took me days to figure out how to get connected to SQL Server for the first time from Linux. Thankfully, there are quite a few walkthroughs out there now, and FreeTDS has come a long way since that time.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually have this running on my setup.  My best advice is to get on the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) bus.

https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php is where you're going to want to look for installing PHP and related items.  I don't remember exactly what I did but it wasn't particularly difficult.

First you'll need FreeTDS.

```
brew install freetds
```

Then, add [Jose's](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php) formulas to your homebrew (instructions on the github page).  After that,

```
brew install php5x --with-mssql  

brew options php5x
```

if you need more extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jon Watson's comment,

I've tried step 2, and it doesn't work. check my issue here https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2180

Step 3 is broken link and I think it's the same with step 2.

I also tried linux ODBC driver for Laravel (there are 2, google it), **both doesn't work too**. Although my simple test php works in both DBLIB and ODBC (compiled using official microsoft odbc unix driver).

Step 4 definitely works, BUT you must use IIS for best stability.

That leaves step 1. OR,

Ditch Laravel4 and use good ol' AdoDB http://adodb.sourceforge.net/ which I've been using since 2006 and still working superbly (although not modern like Laravel) configure it using tutorial in http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP

I wonder why they don't build sqlsrv driver for linux too....